# Is there a way to pass 8-channel image to keras for CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The problem: I am unable to process CNN model for training 8-channel .TIF images.

Expected Output: Map training data (`train_ds`) via gdal and train model.

**data (images)**:
n = 600 
shape = (256, 256, 8)

**data structure:**

project_photos/ 
....classes/ 
......barren/ 
......agriculture/ 
......wooded/

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import pathlib

>print (tf.__version__)
2.1.0
data_dir = ".\projects\keras\projectA\project_photos\classes")
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.tif')))
>print(image_count)
600

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'), shuffle=False)
list_ds = list_ds.shuffle(image_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

batch_size = 32
img_height = 256
img_width = 256

>for f in list_ds.take(5):
>  print(f.numpy())

b'/home/projects/keras/projectA/project_photos/classes/barren/12345_b0001.tif'
b'/home/projects/keras/projectA/project_photos/classes/wooded//12345_w0001.tif'
b'/home/projects/keras/projectA/project_photos/classes/barren/12345_b0002.tif'
b'/home/projects/keras/projectA/project_photos/classes/agriculture//12345_a0001.tif'
b'/home/projects/keras/projectA/project_photos/classes/wooded/12345_w0002.tif'

# tree structure
>class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in data_dir.glob('*')]))
print(class_names)

['barren' 'agriculture' 'wooded']

# train/validation split
val_size = int(image_count * 0.2)
train_ds = list_ds.skip(val_size)
val_ds = list_ds.take(val_size)

def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
  # Integer encode the label
  return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # resize the image to the desired size
  return tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

I understand that tensorflow has limited support (experimental) for `decode_tiff`, and even if that did work - I am *unable* to use the latest version of TF that has that update.

This leaves me with attempting workarounds, the following - which have not succeeded:

```py
"""
Updating decode_img(img) in attempt to process 8-channel .TIF raster
"""

#attempt, adding gdal_Open variable to decode_img
## fails due to image path (train_ds) being stored as byte.

x = gdal.Open(file_path)
Error: Not a string.

#attempt, modifying to extract PATH as str().
def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = ''
  for fpath in file_path:
    img = fpath.numy()
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label


>train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
ValueError: len requires a non-scalar tensor, got one of shape Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(0,), dtype=int32)

#attempt, processing outside of `.map`, works just fine.

imgList = []
for elem in train_ds:
  img = elem.numpy()
  img = img.decode()
  imgList.append(img)

file_path = imgList[0]
raster = gdal.Open(file_path)
bands = [raster.GetRasterBand(k + 1).ReadAsArray() for k in range (raster.RasterCount)]
n_bands = len(bands)
img_array = np.stack(bands,2)
img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img_array, dtype = tf.float32)
img = tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])

print(type(img))
print(img.numpy().shape)

<class: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
(256, 256, 8)
```

So, any ideas on how I can get this to work within the TF framework - getting TF to process the raster via .map?

Comment: Please include your tensorflow version, and the full traceback, It would also be nice if the example your provide is minimal.

Comment: version (2.1.0) [added]. Pls rephrase second part, unreadable.

Comment: [ How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The traceback is the python error. Could you add it?